# Htaccess how to invert extension and name

Tags: .htaccess

I tried to invert the name and the extension of a requested file, but unsuccesfully.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)$ $2.$1
```

I tried that, but is not working.

Comment: I'm curious about why you want to do that ? Also, do you want a silent/internal rewrite or an external redirect ? Is this for file in document root folder (`/file.ext`) or in subdirectories (`/sub/xyz/file.ext`) ?

Comment: "It is not working" is not a valid problem description. Do you get an error? Then tell us what kind of error? Do you see unicorns appear on your screen? Well... then I fear there is no fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/]+)\.([^/]+)$ /$1$3.$2 [L]
```